# replace all ocurrence of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I upload a picture to my Node API, and in my database the path of the picture is like this: `public\uploads\img\myImage-1551119543339.png`, but I want to return to anyone requesting the imgs like this `public/uploads/img/myImage-1551119543339.png`. How do a save the path?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. [How to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the back-slashes have to be escaped in the original string. Then use split and join on the forward and back slash

```js
var str="public\\uploads\\img\\myImage-1551119543339.png";
console.log(str.split("\\").join('/'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern to replace back slashes.

```js
var str="public\\uploads\\img\\myImage-1551119543339.png";
console.log(str.replace(/\\/g,'/'));
```